# How to group certain file-information into several objects based on field description in Java

Tags: java, hashmap, line, bufferedreader, filereader

I have a pretty complex textfile, build like below:

FieldA-Value

FieldB-Value

.
.
.

FieldC-Value

FieldD-Value

.
.
.

FieldC-Value

...

Now my goal is to build out of every - lets call it Fieldgroup - an Object. I start with the Header (FieldA and FieldB) and readin all the lines until I find the first FieldC. Then everything is stored in an Header Object.

Now the problem: As you can see FieldC and so on appears multiple times. After I stored the header and I go look for the FieldC, it immediately stops (of course) at the first occurence and builds the Object, without all the information that comes behind.

So basically what I want is to get all the Data of all the C-Fields.

I am using a FileReader in combination with LineNumberReader. (Below shortened up code).

```
fr = new FileReader(file);
lnr = new LineNumberReader(fr);

while((line = lnr.readLine()) != null){

    // code to split in fieldnames and values and put them in a map

    if(name.equals(A)){

        new ObjectFromClassA(map);
    }else if(name.equals(C){

        //Here is the Problem
        new ObjectFromClassB(map);

}

}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should only call `new` when the name is A. You should call `Object.update(map)` whenever name equals something else (for example C). You have to write this `Object.update()` method yourself in the Object class. This method should add the given fields to the instance.

Comment: Maybe I shouldve been more clear... both calls of  `new` are two different classes Im creating an object off. So the first one is for the Header (A). And the second one is for the body of that. Now it can also happen that the file contains multiple objects which means that there can be a new Header in the file with new content. Even if I update everything it doesnt solve the problem that the first occurence of C which is found leads to the case that Im building an Object without all of its data afterwards till the next C-"Package".

Comment: Edit: the `map` is actuallys being updated permanently and the Objects are added to Lists, so I can read them out later.

Comment: You probably want to keep a reference to the created ObjectB outside the while-block. Then in the `name.equals(C)` block, you want to check whether the ObjectB is null. If it's null, then you create a new one, if it's not null, you add this data to the existing ObjectB.